# css images js not loading after url htaccess rewrite rule

Tags: php, url, url-rewriting

i have use this for url rewrite

old url

```
   http://localhost/project/productSearch?id_category=7&id_size=23&id_colour=89 


    Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
    # Turn mod_rewrite on
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule productSearch/(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)$ productSearch.php?id_category=$1&id_size=$2&id_colour=$3 [L]

    ## hide .php extension snippet
    # To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]

    # To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
    RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

now new url

```
           http://localhost/project/productSearch/7/23/89
```

But images,css.jqyery not loading on this page

Any Idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your page at URL

```
http://localhost/project/productSearch/7/23/89
```

Gets rewritten to

```
http://localhost/project/productSearch?id_category=7&id_size=23&id_colour=89
```

Because of that all resource reference URLs point to wrong location now. You have to change the resource reference URLs to match the new page URL (post rewrite URL).

For example - if you had referred to an image in the earlier case with URL

```
<img src="../../../../images/image.png">
```

Now it will be

```
<img src="../images/image.png">
```